# Jquery - How to move a div(with img inside) from beginning to end of list

Tags: jquery

I am creating a very, small and simple slideshow and one of the feature of this slideshow, is that you can see the upcoming picture at the bottom of the main picture.

So this is my html

```
<div id="secondPictures">
  <div class="containerPicture">
     <img src="/upload/inv/23/c3.jpg" alt="image1" class="wide">
  </div>
  <div class="containerPicture">
     <img src="/upload/inv/23/c5.jpg" alt="image2" class="wide">
  </div>
  <div class="containerPicture">
     <img src="/upload/inv/23/c08.jpg" alt="image3" class="wide">
  </div>
  <div class="containerPicture">
     <img src="/upload/inv/23/c98.jpg" alt="image4" class="wide">
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want from there, it's to set an Interval and every X time, take the first div .containerPicture and put it at the very bottom, but still inside of #secondPictures, and so on.

My jquery so far of my slideshow..

```
$(function() {
$('#mainPicture > img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() {
    $('#mainPicture > img:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#mainPicture');
    var _elementClone = $('#secondPictures > .containerPicture:first').clone();
    $('#secondPictures > .containerPicture:first').remove();
    $('#secondPictures').append(_elementClone);
}, 1500);
});
```

This is working right now but I am guessing...is there a better approch to do this?  Like, is there a function for that kind of situation?? thx!

Comment: Your jQuery selectors don't match the ids in the HTML.

Comment: Is somewhat confusing when selectors in script don't match html. WHat is `'#secondPictures` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this to move the first div to last:

```
$("#pictures>div:first").insertAfter("#pictures>div:last");
```

Look here : http://jsfiddle.net/224Mu/

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for. One easy line ;) thanks!!!! (I will accept your answer in 2 min)

Answer (score 1):

Moving elements in the DOM is quite easy. You can just add the element where you want it, and it will be moved there, as an element can only be in one place in the DOM.

You can use the `append` method to move the first image container last:

```
$('#pictures').append($('#pictures .containerPicture:eq(0)'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4jRQ/

Using `appendTo` works the same by just swapping the selectors:

```
$('#pictures .containerPicture:eq(0)').appendTo($('#pictures'));
```